# redirecting domain to subdirectory with php or apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?url.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www-static [L]
</IfModule>
```

ok the apache config above works well. it does

```
url.com to url.com/www-static = www.myurl.com/www-static
```

**1. can we do something like in apache ?**

```
url.com = www.myurl.com/www-static without adding the /www-static on the url ?
```

**2. how about in php ? or its better on apache? ( lets say we have thousand of domain redirecting to a spesific folder that we fetch from the database )**

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 0):

Use a bootstrap and the MVC pattern. This way you can detect the referring URL and fetch the content that you want to show... it's how all of those search engine cloaker scripts work (which it sounds like you are trying to do).